# Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error using Java Servlet, Netbeans ide 11.1 tomcat 9.029

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, tomcat9

Whenever I try to call a servlet it's giving me "*Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error*".

Even when I create a new servlet in a new web aplication just to test it, it gives the same error. The weird thing is that it was working fine yesterday, and I didn't change a thing in the project

page:

```
excepción
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet [Servlets.Inicio]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)


causa raíz
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Servlets.Inicio.<init>(Inicio.java:1)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

log:

```
27-Nov-2019 14:22:58.404 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-309] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marcando el servlet [Inicio] como no disponible
27-Nov-2019 14:22:58.404 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-309] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet [Inicio]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        at Servlets.Inicio.<init>(Inicio.java:1)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I'm using Netbeans 11.1, and Tomcat 9.029 for the server.

I also tried changing the server to Glassfish, but I get the same error.

Comment: More information is needed so that others can attempt to replicate your problem. Please update your question based on the following: [1] What type of project is this: Ant vs. Maven vs. Gradle? [2] Did you create the project using the NetBeans project wizard? If so, what did you do?  [3] Are you using *web.xml* or annotations for your servlet? [4] Is it possible to post the  source of your servlet, and also *web.xml* if your project uses it? [5] What version of JDK are you using? [6] Is this the only servlet/project giving you a problem, or do all of your servlets always fail in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. I update to new NetBeans v11.2 and the servlet run !!!

The servler run also with NetBeans 8.2, the problem is NB v11.1